# Try to install a R package in R 3.6.0

Tags: r, package, installation

I just installed R 3.6.0 and was trying to install package. However, it says

> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()

and there is no response at all.

Reinstalling of R has been attempted.

Comment: Have you tried to install wanted package with `install.packages("PACKAGE")`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do when you get that message? Are you using the basic R GUI or RStudio? Are you clicking a button or typing a command?

Comment: Thank you all. It finally works by typing in 'install.packages("PACKAGE")'. But then I wonder why no window pops up to show the list of all packages.

Comment: Is there supposed to be three colons in there?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an R3.6.0 bug to me. Anyway if you just type "install.packages()" you can still install packages through graphical selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run R as Administrator (right-click on the R icon). So, if the R package installation menu is not working, use the command `install.packages()`.